# Live text chat box in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rubygems

Sorry if this comes across as a stupid question.

Take a look at https://btc-e.com/

I'm trying to implement a live text chat box that logged in users can type into and everyone sees their message. They would be authenticated through devise.

Is there any gem that can help with this. How would someone with little programming experience implement this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Is there a stack exchange website where I can ask for recommendations?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You're supposed to do your homework, then it's OK to ask questions when you've done your research and are aware of what's out there and have tried some things. Stack Exchange isn't the starting point of the journey, it's where you go when you've set out and are stuck. Your particular question is very broad and needs to show your effort to solve the problem. What you're after involves many technologies that you need to be aware of, then you can ask more focused questions.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Just some feedback for you, you could be a bit less defensive.

Comment: There's no defensiveness at all. I'm trying to help you get the most out of the site, while remaining within its guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try watching these railscasts video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

these have the good demonstrated example how to set up live text chat box.

Comment: Thanks you, that's what I'm doing now!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html

I haven't used it myself, but I've used socket.io in Node.js, and it seems like the same thing just for Ruby on rails.

Comment: How do I use this? Is there a gem I can use? I'm a total newbie here.

Comment: Start here : http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/clients.html
Then just follow the steps that fits your project